# Replacing double quotes while sending parameter to javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is JSFiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/5kdek3vn/

I have button as follows:

```
<button class="buttoncss" title="Modify This Artifact File" onclick="setFileDescriptionForUpdate('!@#$%^&amp;*()_+-=~`{}|[]\:" ;'&lt;&gt;?,.="" ','state.dat','167','1','c:\\pp_artifactsuploadedfiles\evalid_318\state.dat');">Modify</button>
```

in this on click i am calling `setFileDescriptionForUpdate` function whose first parameter is string and is as follows:

```
!@#$%^&*()_+-=~`{}|[]\:";'<>?,./
```

when " is involved in string it creates problem.

What changes i can make to avoid this??

Please help me.

Comment: I've checked your fiddle the problem is you are getting this error..
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`

Get rid of that...

Comment: best way NOT to use inline javascript. set onclick listener inside *.js, not inside *.html. for example $(".buttoncss").click(function(){ /*here you can call any functions with any params*/ })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below Code :-

```
var user = "Hi \" User";
var test = user.replace("\"", "");
document.body.innerHTML = test;
```

Answer (score 2):

**HTML escaping** is required if going *inline*.

If you have to use inline javascript in html then you have to escape it

```
& becomes &amp;
< becomes &lt;
> becomes &gt;
```

In attribute values you must also escape the quote character [spec]:

```
" becomes &quot;
' becomes &#39;
```